# Ionic 2 - Change loader and icon of cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I built an app with ionic 2, but I would like to know how I can modify the loader and the icon of cordova?

The command I used to generate the app was:

`ionic build android`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$ ionic resources` - http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-icon-and-splash-screen-generation-16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should take a look at the ionic-cli repository it has all the info you are looking for.
[check it here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli#icon-and-splash-screen-image-generation)

There's also a blog post in Ionic official blog
[check it here](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/)